# Rails3 multi-select form and database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, associations, multi-select

I have an app where I'm doing a collection_select on a model.  I need to be able to select multiple ids from SpecialEquipment.

Here is my select statement:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:special_equipment_id, SpecialEquipment.all, :id, :name,  {}, {:multiple => true, :class => 'select'})%>
```

I'm using select2 gem to make the UI more appealing and it allows me to select multiple ids however when the form goes to write to the database it only writes the first selection.

```
1.9.3p194 :004 > Call.last.special_equipment
  Call Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "calls".* FROM "calls" ORDER BY "calls"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  SpecialEquipment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "special_equipments".* FROM "special_equipments" WHERE "special_equipments"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<SpecialEquipment id: 1, name: "O2", created_at: "2012-06-27 21:43:41", updated_at: "2012-06-27 21:43:41">
```

What am I doing wrong?  I have associations setup as follows:

Call.rb
belongs_to :special_equipment

Special_Equipment.rb
 has_many :calls

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think I should be using a HABTM association to make this work.  Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by using a has_many :through association and writing the form input to a join table.  I'm now able to multi-select and keep the records properly.